# Multi-level beta regression package for R?

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis, beta-distribution

I want to run multi-level beta regression with two levels (years nested within geographic pixels). I know about betareg, but as far as I know it doesn't have a multi-level option.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you will have to implment yourself. Maybe you can use WinBugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There gamlss package fits regressions to simultaneously estimate the conditional distributions of shape, scale, and location parameters for many sampling distributions, include several parameterizations of the beta. This package also allows for the fitting of varying intercept and varying slope models. While it is not a pre-packaged multi level Bayesian beta regression, it's pretty close.